# First and second access violation on boot::exception messages

Tags: c++, exception, memory-management, boost, windows-8

I am having a problem debugging a first access violation which is crashing my desktop application on Windows 8. It is especially frustrating as the crash does not happen on my Windows 8 VM which I am using for development, only on the tablet device on which it is supposed to run.

I have  boost::exception which is defined thus:

```
struct ExceptionBase: virtual std::exception, virtual boost::exception {};
struct DEVICES_COMMUNICATION_API CDeviceException: virtual ExceptionBase {};
typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_device_message, std::string> device_message;
```

There is also an inline function to set the error message:

```
inline void throwDeviceException(std::string message)
{
  CDeviceException de = CDeviceException()
     << (device_message(std::string(message)));
  BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(de);
}
```

Also another inline function to retrieve the error message:

```
inline std::string retrieveDeviceExceptionMessage(CDeviceException de)
{
    return *(boost::get_error_info<device_message, CDeviceException>(de));
}
```

The exceptions are caught in my application (which is a server) and then then assigned into a class which was generated with protobuf, and then serialized. The code that catches the exception and stores it in the class is a functor run inside a boost thread:

```
struct invoke_fn
{
   void operator()(devices::server::CDeviceServer& server,
                   boost::promise<void>&           boostPromise,
                   CDeviceClientRequest&           request,
                   CDeviceServerResponse&          response)
   {
      try
      {
         server.invoke(request, response);
         boostPromise.set_value();
      }
      catch (devices::util::CDeviceException &e)
      {
         std::string message = devices::util::retrieveDeviceExceptionMessage(e);
         response.set_errormessage(message);
      }
      catch (std::exception &e)
      {
         std::string message(e.what());
         response.set_errormessage(message);
      }
   }
};
```

And the code that sets the error message on the response object, which was auto-generated by protobuf, is:

```
inline void CDeviceServerResponse::set_errormessage(const ::std::string& value) {
  set_has_errormessage();
  if (errormessage_ == &::google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString) {
    errormessage_ = new ::std::string;
  }
  errormessage_->assign(value);
}
```

This uses assign() to copy the passed in string to the protobuf class. The server request is being run inside it's own boost::thread like this:

```
boost::promise<void>        boostPromise;
boost::unique_future<void>  boostFuture = boostPromise.get_future();
boost::thread               boostThread([&]()
                            {
                               invoke_fn functor;
                               functor(*this,
                                       boostPromise,
                                       request,
                                       response);
                            });

return (boostFuture.wait_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(timeout))
        ==
        boost::future_status::ready);
```

As far as I can tell this code looks OK. However the following stack traces have been observed:

From Dr.Memory:

```
> ~~3868~~
> ~~3868~~ Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS: reading 0x03233e70-0x03233e74 4 byte(s)
> ~~3868~~ # 0 amalgam-devices-communication.dl!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Grow [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring:2226]
> ~~3868~~ # 1 amalgam-devices-communication.dl!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring:1113]
> ~~3868~~ # 2 amalgam-devices-communication.dl!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring:1099]
> ~~3868~~ # 3 amalgam-devices-communication.dl!CDeviceServerResponse::set_errormessage   [c:\workspace\bitbbucket\1edit_amalgam\devices\communication\src\main\c++\protobuf\src\main\cdeviceserverresponse.pb.h:294]
> ~~3868~~ # 4 amalgam-devices-communication.dl!invoke_fn::operator()                     [c:\workspace\bitbbucket\1edit_amalgam\devices\communication\src\main\c++\server\cdeviceserver.cc:156]
> ~~3868~~ # 5 amalgam-devices-communication.dl!<lambda_e4b2ef864a7f24dec10bd7126eadbce1>::operator() [c:\workspace\bitbbucket\1edit_amalgam\devices\communication\src\main\c++\server\cdeviceserver.cc:184]
> ~~3868~~ # 6 amalgam-devices-communication.dl!boost::detail::thread_data<<lambda_e4b2ef864a7f24dec10bd7126eadbce1> >::run [c:\workspace\bitbbucket\1edit_precompiledheaders\desktopdevices\external-sources\boost\thread\detail\thread.hpp:74]
> ~~3868~~ # 7 amalgam-devices-communication.dl!boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function [c:\users\marcusma\source\1edit-prism\boost_1_51_0\libs\thread\src\win32\thread.cpp:190]
> ~~3868~~ # 8 MSVCR110D.dll!beginthreadex                                               +0x1a0    (0x73dce001 <MSVCR110D.dll+0x5e001>)
> ~~3868~~ # 9 MSVCR110D.dll!endthreadex                                                 +0x170    (0x73dce1d1 <MSVCR110D.dll+0x5e1d1>)
> ~~3868~~ #10 KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk                                          +0xd      (0x7735850d <KERNEL32.dll+0x2850d>)
> ~~3868~~ Note: @0:00:44.759 in thread 3868
> ~~3868~~ Note: next higher malloc: 0x03234000-0x03234030
> ~~3868~~ Note: 0x03233e70-0x03233e74 overlaps memory 0x03233e58-0x03233e74 that was freed
> ~~3868~~ Note: instruction: mov    0x18(%eax) -> %ecx
> ~~3868~~
```

The first and second access violations occur at the end curly brace of the first exception handling catch block:

```
catch (devices::util::CDeviceException &e)
{
    std::string message = devices::util::retrieveDeviceExceptionMessage(e);
    response.set_errormessage(message);
} // HERE
```

And Visual Studio debugger stack trace indicates the exception is occurring in ~CDeviceException(), the destructor, whilst trying to free the error_info (the device_message) which was set on the object.

From Visual Studio:

```
First-chance exception at 0x76DA4B32 in amalgam-devices-server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::broken_promise> at memory location 0x030EF55C.
First-chance exception at 0x76DA4B32 in amalgam-devices-server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::broken_promise> at memory location 0x030EF55C.
First-chance exception at 0x76DA4B32 in amalgam-devices-server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x76DA4B32 in amalgam-devices-server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x76DA4B32 in amalgam-devices-server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> > at memory location 0x031EF6C0.
First-chance exception at 0x76DA4B32 in amalgam-devices-server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> > at memory location 0x031EF6C0.
First-chance exception at 0x76DA4B32 in amalgam-devices-server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<devices::util::CDeviceException> at memory location 0x031EF6A8.
First-chance exception at 0x76DA4B32 in amalgam-devices-server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<devices::util::CDeviceException> at memory location 0x031EF6A8.
First-chance exception at 0x76DA4B32 in amalgam-devices-server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: devices::util::CDeviceException at memory location 0x031EF894.
First-chance exception at 0x76DA4B32 in amalgam-devices-server.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: devices::util::CDeviceException at memory location 0x031EF894.
Critical error detected c0000374
```

And the call stack looks like this:

```
ntdll.dll!77a6a9ff()    Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!77a6bcf5()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!77a6ad4a()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!77a2186c()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!779e26e8()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!779e1edb()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!779e217e()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!779e2664()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!779e2664()    Unknown
msvcr110d.dll!_free_base(void * pBlock) Line 50 C
msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg_nolock(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1431   C++
msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse) Line 1265  C++
msvcr110d.dll!operator delete(void * pUserData) Line 54 C++
amalgam-devices-communication.dll!std::allocator<char>::deallocate(char * _Ptr, unsigned int __formal) Line 586 C++
amalgam-devices-communication.dll!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate(char * _Ptr, unsigned int _Count) Line 888    C++
amalgam-devices-communication.dll!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Tidy(bool _Built, unsigned int _Newsize) Line 2265 C++
amalgam-devices-communication.dll!std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >() Line 965 C++
amalgam-devices-communication.dll!invoke_fn::operator()(devices::server::CDeviceServer & server, boost::promise<void> & boostPromise, CDeviceClientRequest & request, CDeviceServerResponse & response) Line 157    C++
>   amalgam-devices-communication.dll!<lambda_e4b2ef864a7f24dec10bd7126eadbce1>::operator()() Line 185  C++
amalgam-devices-communication.dll!boost::detail::thread_data<<lambda_e4b2ef864a7f24dec10bd7126eadbce1> >::run() Line 75 C++
amalgam-devices-communication.dll!boost::`anonymous namespace'::thread_start_function(void * param) Line 191    C++
msvcr110d.dll!_callthreadstartex() Line 354 C
msvcr110d.dll!_threadstartex(void * ptd) Line 337   C
kernel32.dll!7735850d() Unknown
ntdll.dll!779ebf39()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!779ebf0c()    Unknown
```

Any help greatly appreciated, we have been trying to track this down now for several days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked out what the problem was. The CDeviceResponse object is passed by reference
to the functor in the boost::thread. If the thread times out, the main thread takes over
and the object falls out of scope and is destroyed.

The thread containing the server invocation however is not killed, it continues to run,
until eventually it throws its own exception, and kills the thread. At this point the
object is destroyed again, causing the access violation.

There are 2 possible fixes.

1. Catch the the fact that invokeWithTimeout() has returned false and explicitly kill the thread. That would involve remembering details about the thread, and we wanted the code to be simpler for maintenance so we went for option 2.
2. Define shared pointers for the request and response and pass these to the functor and
   invoke instead. That way when the main thread exists and moves on, only the reference
   count is decremented. When the actual thread then dies, it successfully destroys the object.

However if someone knows of a cleaner way of killing the timed out thread which was invoked
with the code below, then please let me know:

```
boost::promise<void>        boostPromise;
boost::unique_future<void>  boostFuture = boostPromise.get_future();
boost::thread               boostThread([&]()
                            {
                               invoke_fn functor;
                               functor(*this,
                                       boostPromise,
                                       request,
                                       response);
                            });

bool result = (boostFuture.wait_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(timeout))
               ==
               boost::future_status::ready);
>> if result false kill the thread here
return result;
```